# Difference between HTTP vs HTTPS

Tags: http, https

I have one wordpress website, in that am getting lot of errors day by day. So I like to change my normal HTTP to HTTPS. So please can you explain it is very useful and secure for my website.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS

Comment: The question is both offtopic, too broad and covered by Wikipedia. Also most likely HTTPS won't address your error-related problems.

Answer (score 0):

**10,000ft view**...

`http` is an unencrypted protocol for sending and retrieving data from servers in a web browser (among other uses). `https` is the same protocol but wrapper in SSL, a security tool that encrypts communications between the browser and server. This is what what banks and other websites use to ensure your data (like financial info) is protected when sent to your browser and cannot be read by someone on the same network.

Checkout articles like [this](http://www.biztechmagazine.com/article/2007/07/http-vs-https) and google the topic for more info.

Hope this helps.